# Error while configuring Self-hosted ARM agent for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying to create a Self-hosted agent for ARM, following this microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops

I downloaded the agent, extract it. But when I run `./config.sh` I got the following error (this step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines):

```
./config.sh: line 85: ./bin/Agent.Listener: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I'm working on a Rasberry pi.

Does someone know something about this error ?

Comment: Which Linux version do you use?

Comment: Raspbian. `uname` gives me `Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: Well, I just retried this morning and it works..

Comment: @iAmoric I'm having the same issue!